# Some videos or channels not working with Chrome Cast Android

Tags: android, video-streaming, chromecast, channel

We have integrated video streaming as per this link.

https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender

mRemoteMediaPlayer.load(mApiClient, mediaInfo, true)

We are able to play some video or channels with this class or methods. Please find below reference url which is working at our side.

E.g http://iptvcanales.com/xw/peliculas.php?movie=067

But we are not able to play some of the videos or channels with this class or methods. Please find below reference URL which is not working.

E.g http://200.76.77.237/LIVE/H01/CANAL445/PROFILE03.m3u8?-1332%2F1499-20150816T153535.ts=-1'

It's automatically disconnect after some times.